# Dynamically adding multiple values to single point of bar graph in highchart

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I was wondering if anyone knew of jsfiddle examples where stacked bar graphs with multiple values on a single point were changed after their creation. I've seen plenty of examples using setData for single points on a series, but none for multiple.

I currently have the following graphs and would like to put multiple values on each point.

```
window.jQuery(function () {
    //var opportunities_by_month_chart;
    opportunities_by_month_chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Pipeline By Month By Outcome'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['test', 'test2']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Opportunity size in £'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return 'Month: ' + this.x + '<br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': £' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                    'Total: £' + this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
                name: 'Closed Won',
                data: [],
                color: 'green'
            }, {
                name: 'Closed Postponed',
                data: [],
                color: 'orange'
            }, {
                name: 'Closed Lost',
                data: [],
                color: 'red'
            }, {
                name: 'Other',
                data: [],
                color: 'blue'
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9FyGX/2/

If someone could point to an example or add an example to the jsfiddle it would make my day :D

Comment: Ah, think I was just having abit of a moment. The following seems to do the trick: chart.series[0].setData([1, 2, 3, 4], true);                        chart.series[1].setData([2, 3, 4], true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said

```
chart.series[0].setData([1, 2, 3, 4], true);
chart.series[1].setData([2, 3, 4], true);
```

will work. However, the last parameter (true) tells highcharts to redraw the chart. Therefore it's more effecient to call the fist setData with false, and only redraw once you've finished adding the data.

```
chart.series[0].setData([1, 2, 3, 4], false);
chart.series[1].setData([2, 3, 4], true);
```